# This code will display selected checkboxes text in textbox as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This code will display selected checkboxes Text in textbox as in the order i checked it 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

But it will not display selected checkboxes Text in textbox after 9

Partial Class _45seater_WebUserControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim str As String = Nothing
    Dim id As String = Nothing
    Dim ch As String = Nothing
    For Each ctrl As Control In Panel1.Controls

        If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = ctrl
            UpdatePanel1.FindControl("chk")
            If chk.Checked = True Then
                If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                    TextBox1.Text = chk.Text
                Else
                    Dim SearchString As String = chk.Text
                    id = TextBox1.Text
                    If id.Contains(SearchString) <> -1 Then
                        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "," + chk.Text
                    Else

                    End If

                End If
            Else
                Dim SearchString As String = chk.Text
                id = TextBox1.Text
                If id.Contains(SearchString) <> -1 Then

                Else
                    id = RemoveSubString(id, chk.Text)
                    TextBox1.Text = id
                End If

            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Function RemoveSubString(ByVal stringvalue As String, ByVal stringremove As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer = stringvalue.IndexOf(stringremove)
    If pos > 0 Then
        Return stringvalue.Remove(pos - 1, stringremove.Length + 1)
    ElseIf pos = 0 Then
        If stringvalue.Contains(",") <> -1 Then
            Return stringvalue.Remove(pos, stringremove.Length)
        Else
            Return stringvalue.Remove(pos, stringremove.Length + 1)
        End If

    End If
    Return stringvalue
End Function
```

End Class

can any body show after chekbox10,checkbox11,checkbox12 in text box as 10,11,12 ......so on  using this code

Comment: better, can you also post your ASPX markup?

Comment: I didnt understand what would u asking about !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand that requirement but i think the only thing the function should do is to print the ID's of all checked CheckBoxes in a TextBox.

Why do you complicated it, this works too:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
For Each control As Control In form1.Controls
    If TypeOf control Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked Then
        TextBox1.Text &= control.ID & ","
    End If
Next
'remove last comma'
If TextBox1.Text.Length <> 0 Then TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
```

According to your new informations about the order, try this:

```
    Protected Sub CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim separator As Char = ","c
        If TextBox1.Text.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim allIIDs As New List(Of String)(TextBox1.Text.Split(separator))
            allIIDs.Remove(chk.ID)
            If chk.Checked Then
                allIIDs.Add(chk.ID)
            End If
            TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
            For Each id As String In allIIDs
                TextBox1.Text &= id & separator
            Next
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = chk.ID
        End If
    End Sub
```

To register the [CheckedChanged-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) on the CheckBoxes you have to add following on aspx for every Checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" />
```

or if you are lazy and want to do that in Codebehind, add following in Page_Init:

```
  Private Sub WebForm1_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        For Each control As Control In Me.form1.Controls
            If TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
                Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(control, CheckBox)
                chk.AutoPostBack = True
                AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckedChanged
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is complecated because it displays the ids as the order you checked it, if you checked checkbox1 then checkbox2 then it will display in textbox as checkbox1, checkbox2

and if you checked checkbox2 first then checkbox1 then it will display in textbox as checkbox2, checkbox1

Comment: How to display checkbox checked id in the order as i checked it... ??

Comment: if i check first checkbox1 then checkbox2 then in textbox it appear as checkbox1, checkbox2

and

f i check first checkbox2 then checkbox1 then in textbox it appear as checkbox2, checkbox1

How to Do that ???

Comment: ID i wanna display ..... text of checkbox instead of IDs then where to modify the code to display checkbox text instead of IDS

Comment: It works, do you have registered the event handler on the Checkboxes?
I have a new version without the ViewState approach, only with Textbox.Text.

Comment: How to register this, i used VS 2008 and asp.net (vb)

Comment: `<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" />`

Comment: But if i use 5000 checkboxes then i have to do this in all  5000 checkboxes ?

Comment: See my updates and consider to add those informations in your question before you post ;-)

Comment: As i provide you ..... my above code is works perfectly.... but it shows the checkbox text as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in textbox till checkbox9 is works perfctly but when i dirctly check checkbox10 checkbox11 checkbox12 then it will not diaplsy checkbox text in textbox it will diaply in textbox as 11,,, when i check checkbox10, checkbox11,checkbox12 and so on ...

Comment: The code above works also with IDs greater than 9.
You only need to add the event handler in Page.Init(below in my answer) and the CheckedChanged-Event Handler.
If you don't need the complete ID, you only have to modify the CheckedChanged a little. That should be no problem.

Comment: But i wanna display checkbox text not ids ....

plz provide a single and short code to do that ...

Comment: Event handler is not the perfect solution for that ..because if i need 5000 checkboxes then we r not able to add event ahndler in all 5000 checkboxes ...

Comment: Hey tim ...if i check checkbox10 with checkbox.text=10 then the checkbox text would be appear in textbox as 1

Comment: If you want to store the CheckBox.Text, then you only need to replace chk.ID with chk.Text in the CheckedChanged-Handler. I really don't see the problem here. Additionally t think you have not yet understood, that my solution works for 5000 Checkboxes without any problems and you don't need to add the event handler for every checkbox. I mentioned that at the very bottom of my answer. Also consider to mark answeers at least as useul when people try to help you ;-)

Cheers.

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes and 1 textbox in webform if i type in textbox 1,2 then checkbox1 & 2 will be checked !

directly after if i type 3,4 in textbox then the all 4 checkboxes will be checked

But i want.

the checkbox will be checked accorcding to the data displayed in text box ..if textbox1.text =1,2 then only checkbox1 and checkbox2 will be checked and others are remain unchecked

and if i checked checkbox3 and checkbox4 then only 3 and 4 will be checked and others are unchecked.

how to do that in page load event

I want to do this with 50000 checkboxes and more which displayed in my webform

Comment: Update your original question with this informations, because it is unreadable in this comments.

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes and 1 textbox in webform if i type in textbox 1,2 then checkbox1 & 2 will be checked ! directly after if i type 3,4 in textbox then the all 4 checkboxes will be checked But i want. the checkbox will be checked accorcding to the data displayed in text box ..if textbox1.text =1,2 then only checkbox1 and checkbox2 will be checked and others are remain unchecked and if i checked checkbox3 and checkbox4 then only 3 and 4 will be checked and others are unchecked. how to do that in page load event I want to do this with 50000 checkboxes and more which displayed in my webform

Comment: Heyyy Tim check out this link for my query ..what i want ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb