# How to check checkboxes according to textbox text !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If in textbox the default textbox value id 1,2,3,4,5,6 ...... upto 55

then the following checkboxes would be checked according to the text display in text box...

if textbox1.text =1,2,3 then in my webform checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 would be checked ... on page load event...

how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim splitted as String() = MyTextBox.Text.Split(",")

For Each id As String in splitted
  Dim ctrl as Control = Page.FindControl("checkbox" & id)

  If Not control Is Nothing Then
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox)
    chkbox.Checked = True
  End If
Next
```

I'm actually a C# programmer, so not 100% if the VB.NET syntax is correct. Another NB! is that this sample only works if the checkboxes are directly in your ASP.NET page. If they're ie. inside an ASP:Panel, then you'll have to use "MyPanel.FindControl" istead of Page.FindControl

Answer (score 0):

55 checkboxes? You could have lots of if...else to check each number, but I would create a collection of checkboxes. Then parse the number in the text box check it is in range and then simply look up correct checkbox to check according using the value as an index.

Another thought: It sounds like one and only one checkbox should be set at a time? If so, you should replace them with a group of radio buttons. As well as being easier to code, it avoids duplicate checkbox checks, and signals to the user that only one can be set.

Comment: Hey winwaed please check this... whatz wrong with this code :

i have ckeckboxes with text checkbox1 checkbox2 checkbox3....to checkbox55 i wanna display selected checkboxes text in textbox if i checkboxes betweet checkbox1 to checkbox9 it will display the selected checkbox text in textbox as 1,2,3,4,...till 9..but it will not display after checkbox10 to checkbox55 text in textbox ...

review this url for my coding for this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172966/this-code-will-display-selected-checkboxes-text-in-textbox-as-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: hi.... a little more modification i need in that also ....

means if i have four checkboxes with text respectively 1 2 3 4 when i type 1,2 then checkbox1 and checkbox2 will be checked .... and after that i will type 3,4 then checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4 all the checkbox will be checked but i want which i type in textbox those textbox will be checked others are remained unchecked !!

Comment: My radio button suggestion should be ignored if multiple checked check boxes are valid It is difficult to understand your required logic beyond that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb

Comment: Sir plz solv my query : mentioned here click her to see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb